# I want to delete my Whatsapp account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I don't want to appear on my friend's phone. I want to delete my Whatsapp account. Will my number disappear from my all friend's Whatsapp friend list when I delete my Whatsapp account? Basically, how can I remove my number from everyone's Whatsapp account?

Comment: I am using samsug galaxy y GT-S5360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete your whatsapp account through the following steps.

1. Open WhatsApp.
2. Press the [Menu Button] => Settings => Account => [Delete My Account].
3. Enter your phone number in the *full international format* and tap [Delete My Account].

Please keep in mind that deleting your account is an irreversible process, we cannot undo a deletion if you complete the process by accident.

Goto [whatsapp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/21119703) for more infomation

Comment: but my friend did it for me.. but still his account and his chat history is appearing on my phone. :( means my friend has deleted his whatsapp account but still he is appearing in my whatsapp contacts and his chat history is also appearing.

Comment: Then Download the app again, log-in and go through the above steps again. Your account **should go away** if the steps are followed correctly.

Comment: its not working ... :( :(

Comment: Did you use *[Correct international format](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21016748)* ?

Comment: he added +91 before his mobl nmbr.india's code

Comment: Yes `+918234123456`

Comment: ohk. finally just tell me that how longer the whatsapp chat remains in phone when we never delete them by ourself. I mean by what the time the chat get deleted autometicaly

Comment: It won't be deleted *automatically*. You can do it manually with a long press on the full chat conversation or the individual message. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your account will be deleted permanently 30 days after you deactivate it. So after deleting your account, don't use your WhatsApp account again for 30 days.